# Create Haar Cascade in OpenCV 3 without using the OpenCV applications

Tags: c++, opencv, haar-classifier

I need to train my own Haar Cascade classifier using OpenCV 3.X writing my own code without using OpenCV application (opencv_createsamples, opencv_haartraining), but I'm not able to find any reference neither in the OpenCV documentation or in some tutorial.

Everything say "use opencv applications", even in the official documentation.

Where I can find at least some base classes reference?

Comment: Well you can look up the source code of those apps: [opencv/apps](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/apps): [createsamples](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/apps/createsamples), [annotation](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/apps/annotation), [traincascade](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/apps/traincascade) and [visualization](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/apps/visualisation).

Comment: I already did that, but for instance createsamples use the function cvCreateTrainingSamples, but 1. you cannot found it in documentation 2. the cv prefix tell it use the c old library.

Comment: That function is declared/implemented in the files besides [`createsamples.cpp`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/apps/createsamples/createsamples.cpp), [`utility.hpp`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/apps/createsamples/utility.hpp) and [`utility.cpp`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/apps/createsamples/utility.cpp). Those apps seem to define multiple custom functions and classes with names starting with `cv`, but those are not part of the library itself.

Comment: Where can I find python implementation of these scripts?
I can't find these scripts with my OpenCV installation. So instead of messing around with a new installation of OpenCV, I would like to use python implementation of these scripts and run using the interpreter.